# Ubuntu 20.04 — build/update-linux-sandbox.sh, no such file or directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, google-chrome

I used `google-chrome name.pdf` to open my file in Chrome, but it output an error message as below:

`1007/010233.322709:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox! Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly`

Although the browser did open my file, the process didn't seem to end correctly (no new prompt for more than 10 sec after the error message showed up), so I had to ctrl C.

I've tried to use `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-setuid-sandbox`, but they didn't work for me. The error remained the same. When I followed online documentation and tried `build/update-linux-sandbox.sh`, another error came up

`bash: build/update-linux-sandbox.sh: No such file or directory`

I'm relatively new to Linux. Now what should I do about it?

Comment: did you found an answer to this?